# SQlite update incremental counter

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I have the following table:

```
Group | SubGroup | id  
'A'   | 'AA'     |  2  
'A'   | 'AB'     |  4  
'A'   | 'AC'     |  6    
'B'   | 'BA'     |  2  
'B'   | 'BB'     |  9
```

And I would like to update the id column to have sequentially value for each group:

```
Group | SubGroup | id  
'A'   | 'AA'     |  1  
'A'   | 'AB'     |  2  
'A'   | 'AC'     |  3  
'B'   | 'BA'     |  1  
'B'   | 'BB'     |  2
```

I used a query to ask the value and got it but don't know how to make the update.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_tbl (groupa TEXT, subgroup TEXT, num INTEGER);  
INSERT INTO temp_tbl(groupa,subgroup,num) VALUES ('A','AA',2);   
INSERT INTO temp_tbl(groupa,subgroup,num) VALUES ('A','AB',4);  
INSERT INTO temp_tbl(groupa,subgroup,num) VALUES ('A','AC',6);  
INSERT INTO temp_tbl(groupa,subgroup,num) VALUES ('B','BA',2);  
INSERT INTO temp_tbl(groupa,subgroup,num) VALUES ('B','BB',9);
```

The query:

```
SELECT t9.groupa,t9.subgroup, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_tbl as t8  
WHERE t8.groupa=t9.groupa AND t8.num<=t9.num ) cnt FROM temp_tbl as t9


'A'   | 'AA'     |  1  
'A'   | 'AB'     |  2  
'A'   | 'AC'     |  3  
'B'   | 'BA'     |  1  
'B'   | 'BB'     |  2
```

Now I would like to update the field accordingly. How could I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I used the following SQL example:   CREATE TABLE temp_tbl (groupa TEXT, subgroup TEXT, num INTEGER);    
 INSERT INTO temp_tbl(groupa,subgroup,num) VALUES ('A','AA',2);   
 INSERT INTO temp_tbl(groupa,subgroup,num) VALUES ('A','AB',4);  
 INSERT INTO temp_tbl(groupa,subgroup,num) VALUES ('A','AC',6);  
 INSERT INTO temp_tbl(groupa,subgroup,num) VALUES ('B','BA',2);  
 INSERT INTO temp_tbl(groupa,subgroup,num) VALUES ('B','BB',9);

Comment: How could I include SQL SELECT QUERY n the comments? I always got error

Comment: Show the query that returns the correct values.

Comment: How could I upload the query to the site? I write it but the site can't enable me to add the query. It always return error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use correlated subquery with `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE temp_tbl 
SET num = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM temp_tbl as t8  
           WHERE t8.groupa=temp_tbl.groupa 
             AND t8.num<=temp_tbl.num );
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ff9a6/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════╗
║ groupa  ║ subgroup  ║ num ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════╣
║ A       ║ AA        ║   1 ║
║ A       ║ AB        ║   2 ║
║ A       ║ AC        ║   3 ║
║ B       ║ BA        ║   1 ║
║ B       ║ BB        ║   2 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════╝
```

Keep in mind that your code to generate nums will fail if `id` is not unique in subgroup.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/51e69/1/0)**</kbd>